# Cpp operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

I saw in some books that assignment operator ,function call operator etc can be overloaded by using member functions but not by friend function.Why certain operators can not overloaded  by using friend function ??

Comment: Seems like you are talking about C++....edit your Tag.

Comment: Because the standard says so. I don't see how this can be objectively and productively answered. VTC.